# facebook graph error invalid signature

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

been wrestling with the facebook graph api a while now and am still not able to get what I want.
What am I missing? I have this code just as a test:

```
<?php
            // );
            $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
              'app_id' => '{313084575421679}',
              'app_secret' => '{APP_SECRET}',
              'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
              ]);

            try {
              // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
              $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', '{APP_TOKEN}');
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
              echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
              exit;
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
              echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
              exit;
            }

            $user = $response->getGraphUser();

            echo 'Name: ' . $user['name'];
            ?>
```

it gives me this error `Graph returned an error: Invalid OAuth access token signature.`

later I want to retrieve al, the photo's links so I can create a collage of the pictures in my album.

Comment: Sorry to bump, but anybody who cam help me out with this?

Comment: The app access token is not supposed to contain the `{` and the `}`, might be the issue here. Can you remove them? Same applies to the App ID and the Secret

Comment: Thanks Björn! That did the trick! If you want the points, you can post an answer and Ill accept it to close this topic